# How can I delete a "content" box in a serially converted .odp file without LibreOffice Impress automatically resizing the "title" box

Tags: linux, windows, macos, microsoft-word, libreoffice

I have a .odp file with a single slide (representing a poster) that started life as "Title and 4 Content." The "Title" box has been resized, and the internal formatting changed. Whenever I try to delete one of the original "content" boxes (but not if I try to delete a text box that was added later), regardless of whether it contains text or an image, the title box is resized (probably to its original size) and some or all of the internal formatting is lost. Also, there's a single other content that gets either deleted or moved to somewhere that it's invisible.

Why is this happening? And how can I prevent it, other than by unzipping the .odp, editing content.xml to delete the section in question, then rezipping it (which actually works, indicating that there isn't some essential metadata that has somehow wound up in there).

Now for the gruesome part, that explains why I don't (yet) have a decent MWE:

In the course of the editing process, this poster has been through 2 or 3 cycles of "edit in LO, save as docx, edit in Microsoft Office, save as docx, reopen in (a different version of) Microsoft Office, save as odp" and repeat, due to different software available to different collaborators. To the best of my knowledge, it has not ever been *opened* in the "wrong" editor for the current file type. I suspect that the problem has been introduced somewhere in the process. Nevertheless, right now, it's an odp, it opens fine in LO, I can make other edits in LO, and so this should not be happening, right? Is there any scenario in which it would be reasonable for deleting a content box to change the size of another?

Comment: Documents converted from different file formats in different programs are **always** going to be difficult to edit. I have only seen the behavior where deleting one thing increases the size of another; that is in PowerPoint.

Comment: You may have active an automatic _box_ resizing due to the text (and objects) included inside. So if you delete something that is inside something else... you can have a chain of effects. Without your specific file it is difficult to say. It is one of the problem passing ppt from different OS and program versions. For future you may try to ask to your collaborators to install the same program that reads the `odp` (usually freeware).